# Inno Setup set Setup.exe create date and modified date the same

Tags: inno-setup

By default, when compiling the Setup.exe Inno Setup does not delete the existing file before compiling, meaning that the modified date is likely to be different from the create date unless remembering to manually delete the Setup.exe before compile. What would be the best way to set the date and time the same? I can think of two possible approaches to do this. One would be to use the `TouchDate` and `TouchTime` functions in the Code section at the end of the compile, the other would involve using the ISSP section to automatically delete the Setup.exe prior to compile. I'm not entirely sure if the ISSP option is possible, but which way would be simplest and preferable? Does anyone have any advice on which approach I should take, or is there another option I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most probably a consequence of so called [`file tunelling`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/15/439261.aspx) which has nothing to do with Inno Setup. One way out of this is making a batch script that will run compiler and touch the timestamp after compilation (preprocessor cannot do that because it runs before compilation).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if this is the problem or not. If I delete the Setup.exe prior to running the compiler, I get matching dates and times. It's only if the file already exists that I get a mismatch. Can I perhaps use `DeleteFileNow`. It seems this would be the simplest solution?

Comment: Hmm, it's looking like this is the case. Have tried `#expr DeleteFileNow(SourcePath + "Output\Setup.exe")` in the ISSP section, and this makes no difference. It only works if I manually delete the file prior to running the compile. Annoying!

Comment: ISSP is not able to delete this file with `DeleteFileNow` as when you click Compile the file is set Locked. You could delete any other file, but not the one which you compile. It seems that the Batch script is the easiest solution.

Comment: As always, thanks for the help! Not as elegant a solution as I had hoped for, but a working and simple enough solution none-the-less. In the end I used the FileTouch utility available here www.softtreetech.com/24x7/archive/47.htm and the following batch file: `del /f /q "%~dp0\Output\Setup.exe" |
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Inno Setup 5\Compil32.exe" /cc "%~dp0\MyScript.iss" |
"%~dp0\Tools\FileTouch.exe" /c /w /a "%~dp0\Output\Setup.exe" >NUL`